# Android - java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException When trying to make an array out of an arraylist and insert it into table

Tags: java, android, arrays, json, arraylist

Hello i am new to android studio and i get the error in the title but can't figure out why. I am using volley to get a json file which contains my titles among a few other things. The jsonResponses arraylist should contain all titles. Then i use jsonResponses.toArray to fill an array with the titles. But when i try to display the titles with title.setText the app crashes. At least this is how i understand that this following code should work like. If anyone could point out to me what i might be understanding wrong here i'd appreciate it.

activity_main.java

```
package com.example.sedo;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.widget.TableLayout;
import android.widget.TableRow;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class AssignedThesis extends AppCompatActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_assigned_thesis);
        addTable();

    }


    public void addTable(){
        String url = "http://10.0.2.2/app/assignedthesis.php";
        List<String> jsonResponses = new ArrayList<>();

        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                try {
                    JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("assigned_thesis");
                    for(int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++){
                        JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        String jsonTitle = jsonObject.getString("thesis_title");

                        jsonResponses.add(jsonTitle);
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                error.printStackTrace();
            }
        });

        String[] titles = jsonResponses.toArray(new String[jsonResponses.size()]);   //put my titles in an array

        requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
        TableLayout table = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.table_main);


        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        {
            TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
            TableRow.LayoutParams lp = new TableRow.LayoutParams(0, TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 1f);
            TextView title = new TextView(this);
            title.setText(titles[i]);   //setText for the titles i get from json
            title.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            title.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            title.setLayoutParams(lp);

            TextView prof = new TextView(this);
            prof.setText("Prof " + i);
            prof.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            prof.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            prof.setLayoutParams(lp);

            TextView student = new TextView(this);
            student.setText("Student " + i);
            student.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            student.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            student.setLayoutParams(lp);

            tr.addView(title);
            tr.addView(prof);
            tr.addView(student);
            table.addView(tr);
        }
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml (including just in case)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="#d3d3d3">

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center">

                <TableLayout
                    android:id="@+id/table_main"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginVertical="30dp"
                    android:layout_marginHorizontal="10dp"
                    android:background="#f1f1f1">

                    <TableRow>
                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/colTitle"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Title"
                            android:textStyle="bold"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:gravity="center"/>

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/colProf"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Professor"
                            android:textStyle="bold"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:gravity="center"/>

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/colStudent"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Student"
                            android:textStyle="bold"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:gravity="center"/>

                    </TableRow>

                </TableLayout>
            </RelativeLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: So what's the size of `titles` at execution time, as seen either in the debugger or via logging?

Comment: It says length = 0

Comment: Well that would be a problem if you try to access `titles[0]` and `titles[1]` then, wouldn't it? So presumably `jsonResponses` is empty, which makes a certain amount of sense as you're creating a request which would update it when a response is received, but not actually waiting for any responses. Basically I think this is a problem with how you're using Volley rather than specifically about arrays etc.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer

Comment: I agree. The "2" here seems hard-coded.

for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)